# Using fscanf() when reading from a File in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

Hi so if I have a file (text.txt) that has the following text:

```
This is a file.
```

and in my main method I call fscanf like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)
```

and then do

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

where `fp` is the file pointer and buffer is a char array of size 100 to where I am storing what i am reading from the file,

I get the output:

```
This
```

I understand the reason why - it's because `%s` scans the file upto the first whitespace.

Then if I call

```
fscanf(fp, " is a %s.", buffer)
```

and do

```
printf("%s", buffer)
```

and I get the output

```
file.
```

I was wondering why this is the case, because I thought `%s` would only get the the next string that `fp` is pointing to in the file so shouldn't it be 
`is`
 and not 
`file.`

Comment: Hi, please edit the question and post a [mcve] and format properly.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fscanf parses a **formatted** data coming from a file, the first time when you do:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)
```

you tell the program to read the first word up until the first whitespace, in your example it's `This`.

Now the pointer is at place `This| is a file.` so when you call:

```
fscanf(fp, " is a %s.", buffer)
```

You are telling the program to store into the `buffer` the string at the position where the `%s` is, this means that you read `file.` since you are "discarding" the `" is a "`

To read the `is` you can just do:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)
```

after your first `fscanf()` call where you read `This`

Comment: Note that when you write inline code, you don't need 3 backticks - one is enough. So, `\`foo\``, not `\`\`\`foo\`\`\``

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica oh yeah you're right, I just do three out of habit without thinking

Comment: `note the space before %s` The space is superfluous as `%s` already skips leading whitespace characters

Comment: @Spikatrix makes sense, it's been quite a while since I've used C last and remembered `%c` needs it but couldn't remember if `%s` needed it too